# Use __arglist for C++ function in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I import a C++ function in C#:

```cpp
jboolean (JNICALL *CallBooleanMethod) (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jmethodID methodID, ...);
```

```cs
IntPtr CallBooleanMethod(IntPtr env, IntPtr obj, IntPtr meth, __arglist param);

void Main()
{
   CallBooleanMethod(someHandle, someHandle, someHandle, __arglist(someValue));
}
```

But at runtime, when I call the function, I get an exception:

> Method CallBooleanMethod has a variable argument list. Variable argument lists are not supported in .Net Core.

How can I easily call a similar function? I am using .Net 7.0 with NativeAOT build.

Original exception:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48796

Comment: Wait, you're calling JNI directly from C#? I would write some stub methods in C++ instead.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, Yes, but I don't want to write any C++ code. https://github.com/MrYotic/JNI

Answer (score 0):

You can't do varargs, but you can do multiple declarations of the same function, with different combinations of arguments.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("yourdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="CallBooleanMethod")]
private static extern bool CallBooleanMethod_i(IntPtr env, IntPtr obj, IntPtr meth, int arg1);

[DllImport("yourdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="CallBooleanMethod")]
private static extern bool CallBooleanMethod_d(IntPtr env, IntPtr obj, IntPtr meth, double arg1);

[DllImport("yourdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="CallBooleanMethod")]
private static extern bool CallBooleanMethod_i_d(IntPtr env, IntPtr obj, IntPtr meth, int arg1, double arg2);

void Main()
{
   object[] args = new object[] { someValue };

   // Get env, obj and meth from somewhere
   bool retVal;
   if ( someValue.GetType() == typeof(double) ){
     retVal = CallBooleanMethod_d(env, obj, meth, (double)someValue);
   }  else if (someValue.GetType() == typeof(int) ) {
     retVal = CallBooleanMethod_i(env, obj, meth, (int)someValue);
   }
}
```

Comment: A good code if you know that there are only a few options for arguments. But unfortunately myDll function calls the method, with any arguments. Your code doesn't work for me. But this prompted the idea, if it turns out to use some method of calling the IntPtr method with its own, dynamic arguments - It will be work.

Comment: There is no "with any arguments" - you do not have infinite lines of code. ... It is only necessary to support the combination of argument types which is actually used in your code, this is finite so there are only a finite combination of argument types. .. If later callers need new combinations, then you add them later.